# Сделать одинарные кавычки по умолчанию Sublime3

Tags: sublime-text-3

Коллеги, такой вопрос, при вводе, например, 
Sublime автоматически добавляет двойные кавычки. Есть ли возможность, сделать, чтобы при авто завершении он выставлял одинарные кавычки 

В PhpStorm это легко настраивается, с Sublime нигде не могу найти

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в:

Preferences --> Settings - Syntax-specific

В открывшемся файле необходимо добавить следующую строчку:

```
"auto_match_enabled": false
```

После добавления данной строки, нажмите сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: не работает...ctrl+s - это сохранение файла

Comment: @SergeiDubrovin Не может не работать, я знаю, что ctrl + s это сохранение файла, вы же открываете файл с настройками для саблайма, естественно внесенные изменения следует сохранить

Comment: @SergeiDubrovin я просмотрел Ваш вопрос еще раз, прошу прощения, видимо мы друг друга не так поняли. Но ваш вопрос как то не очень логичен. Саблайм автозаполняет то, что напишете, введете одинарные кавычки - он дополнит их и т.д. Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то вы хотите сделать так, чтобы все время завершалось одинарными кавычками?

Comment: это моя вина, не внимательно посмотрел свой вопрос. Ниже правильно всё седлал. излазил все буржуйские форумы, но ответа так и не нашёл. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Когда задавал вопрос, не заметил, что код стёрся.
Вот, что не могу понять. Когда вводишь

```
<div class="">
```

сублайм автоматически ставит двойные ковычки. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при добавлении class, сублайм, автоматически выставлял одинарные ковычки

```
<div class=''>
```